# Overloading constructor without initialization

Tags: f#

I'm writing a generic class that has two constructors: the first one initializes every field, the second (parameter-less) should not initialize anything.

The only way I found to achieve this is calling the main constructor with "empty" arguments, i.e. Guid.Empty and null. Besides not looking good functional style to my untrained eyes, this means that I have to put a `a' : null` constraint on the second parameter, which I don't want:

```
type Container<'a when 'a : null>(id : Guid, content : 'a) =
    let mutable _id = id
    let mutable _content = content

    new() = Container<'a>(Guid.Empty, null)

    member this.Id
        with get() = _id
        and set(value) = _id <- value

    member this.Content
        with get() = _content
        and set(value) = _content <- value
```

I see two ways to solve this:

- use something like the `default` c# keyword instead of null (does such a thing exist in F#?)
- use a different syntax to specify constructors and private fields (how?)

What is the best way to implement this class?

Comment: Will this type be used from other languages? If not, you can use option types and avoid `Unchecked.defaultof<_>`.

Comment: Yes, this class is exposed as part of a library consumed from C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the type will be used from languages other than F#, the following provides a natural interface in F#, and C#, for example.

```
type Container<'a>(?id : Guid, ?content : 'a) =
    let orDefault value = defaultArg value Unchecked.defaultof<_>
    let mutable _id = id |> orDefault
    let mutable _content = content |> orDefault

    new() = Container(?id = None, ?content = None)
    new(id : Guid, content : 'a) = Container<_>(?id = Some id, ?content = Some content)

    member this.Id
        with get() = _id
        and set(value) = _id <- value

    member this.Content
        with get() = _content
        and set(value) = _content <- value
```

If it will only be used from F#, you can omit the following constructor overloads

```
new(id : Guid, content : 'a) = Container<_>(?id = Some id, ?content = Some content)
new() = Container()
```

because the overload accepting optional args handles both these cases equally well in F#.

Comment: Very nice! Fits my need as the class is used from C#. The class is also serialized by means of an external library (written in C#) that requires a parameterless constructor, so I suppose I'll need the two overloads anyways.

Answer (score 5):

The F# analog to `default` is `Unchecked.default<_>`.  It is also possible to use explicit fields which you don't initialize:

```
type Container<'a>() =
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable _id : Guid
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable _content : 'a

    new (id, content) as this =
        new Container<'a>() then
        this._id <- id
        this._content <- content
```

However, in general, your overall approach is somewhat unidiomatic for F#.  Typically you'd use a simple record type (perhaps with a static method to create uninitialized containers, although this seems to have questionable benefit):

```
type 'a Container = { mutable id : Guid; mutable content : 'a } with
    static member CreateEmpty() = { id = Guid.Empty; content = Unchecked.defaultof<_> }
```

In many situations, you could even use an immutable record type, and then use record update statements to generate new records with updated values:

```
type 'a Container = { id : Guid; content : 'a } 

[<GeneralizableValue>]
let emptyContainer<'a> : 'a Container = 
    { id = Guid.Empty; 
      content = Unchecked.defaultof<_> }

let someOtherContainer = { emptyContainer with content = 12 }
```

Comment: I see how my approach is not very idiomatic for F#, reason is that this class is part of a library that is used from C#. I'll consider removing mutability though, because in this case it may not be needed after all.

Comment: Marked Daniel's answer because it does exactly what I need but this one is excellent too. Thanks!